# Visual Basic read text file and delete files from that file

Tags: vb.net

I know how to tell my program how to read a file but I dont know how to use that information to delete some files from that text file.

Example;

I have a text file called ban.txt inside that file there are two lines with text abc.exe and cba.exe

I want my program to read content of ban.txt and the delete those specified files.

Comment: Please include your current source code, at least a stab at what you are trying to do.

Comment: @db_brad

`Public ban = "ban.txt"`

`Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click`

       `If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(some_dir & ban) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(some_dir & ban)
        End If`

Comment: please put this in the body or your post.

Comment: `Dim fileReader As String`
`If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(some_dir & ban) Then`
`fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(some_dir & ban)`
`If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(darma3 & nazwamoda & "\addons\" & fileReader) Then`
`My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(darma3 & nazwamoda & "\addons\" & fileReader)`
`End If`
`End If`

sorry posting codes here is confusing, this code gernerally works, but only reads 1st line in the text file, lest is ignored

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you know how to read the file and find the file names, then just add this statement to a for-each:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(strFilename)
```

There are also options for displaying error messages and sending the file to the recycle bin.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Test.txt", FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I'm just starting my vb adventure, all "i know" is:

`If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\ban.txt") Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\ban.txt")`

whats next?

Comment: @JerryM ***"but I dont know how to use that information to delete some files from that text file"***. He doesn't as he clearly stated that.

Comment: The **question** was ambiguous as to whether the OP is lacking knowledge on the FileSystem methods or how to parse and loop through the file. Clarification of the question would be helpful to all.